# xClient process consuming CPU -- what is it?

Tags: high-sierra, cpu, macos

Basic question, I can't find anything on Google about it. There's a process that keeps my fans spinning, and consumes about 80% cpu.

`xClient` -- what is it, or how can I find out more about it?

Comment: I goggled on "xclient process mac" and had a bunch of hits. You might try that. Some of the links refer to X11 and Xquartz.  Among other things those are used to run x-windows processes on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Open Activity Monitor and sort by CPU. Then select the item and click the information icon (circle with a lower case i)

Then you can see all the open files and ports. That should give you a ton of system files that make no sense, but you should get a path to the file or some details to post if you can't figure out straight away where it's located and what files it's reading. (Worst case upload the files to a GitHub gist or pastebin and link to me in the comments below)

Answer (score 0):

**What `xClient` is**

I also see this running about once day. This is likely part of the "Snow Inventory Client".

After getting the Process ID (PID) - let's say it's `11211`, I ran this (note that the `$` is the prompt and not part of the command)

```
$ sudo lsof -p 11211
```

and two of the items displayed are:

- `/usr/local/bin/xMetering`
- `/Library/Application Support/Snow Software`

Googling for `xClient` and `xMetering` brings up a PDF describing the Snow Inventory Client. The configuration file (`/etc/snowclient.conf`) mentioned in the PDF also exists on my system, with a `SiteID` being my company's name.

---

**Managing its High CPU usage**

`xClient` is a CPU hog. I use `cputhrottle` to limit it, which can be installed via Homebrew.

Example usage. Suppose `xClient`'s PID is `11211` and you want it to take no more than 10% of CPU (on average). You'd run this in a Terminal:

```
$ sudo cputhrottle 11211 10
```

Note that this is 10% of a single CPU core. The `cputhrottle` command will keep running until the throttled process (in this case, `xClient`) exits.